# break for loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm expecting output like this using for loop

```
name : abc
school : A
year : 2007

name : xyz
school : b
name : 2005

name : pqr
school : c
year : 2003
```

this for loop

```
<?php
            if(count($name) > 1){
                $p = 0;
                for($i=0;$i<count($name); $i++){
                    ?> 
                    <div>name : <?php echo $name[$p];?></div>
                    <?php 
                    $p++;
                }
            }
            ?>  
            <!-- school -->
            <?php
            if(count($school) > 1){
                $g = 0;
                for($i=0;$i<count($school); $i++){
                    ?> 
                    <div>school : <?php echo $school[$g];?></div>
                    <?php 
                    $g++;
                }
            }
            ?>

            <!-- year -->
            <?php
            if(count($year) > 1){
                $y = 0;
                for($i=0;$i<count($year); $i++){
                    ?> 
                    <div>year : <?php echo $year[$y];?></div>
                    <?php 
                    $y++;
                }
            }
            ?>
```

how can i use nested loop to get output like in above.
currently because of above 3 different for loop I'm getting out put like this

```
name : abc
name : xyz
name : pqr
school : A
school : b
school : c
year : 2007
year : 2005
year : 2003
```

Comment: What's your array structure. Post that too

Comment: why multiple variables doing the same thing? you could use `$i` instead of `$p` and so on

Comment: Are $name $school and $year 3 different arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use the loop variable and not a loop and a separate variable!

The code below assume that all three arrays have the same length.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($name); $i++)
{
    ?> 
    <div>name : <?php echo $name[$i];?></div>
    <div>school : <?php echo $school[$i];?></div>
    <div>year : <?php echo $year[$i];?></div>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help , please check as answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($name); $i++)
{
?> 
<div>name : <?php echo $name[$i];?></div>
<div>school : <?php echo $school[$i];?></div>
<div>year : <?php echo $year[$i];?></div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Mattias is right. But he didn't take care of the case when the arrays don't have the same length. To be sure not to request a index from the arrays which isn't set use something like

```
$minArrayCount = min(count($name), count($school), count($year));
for($i=0;$i<$minArrayCount; $i++) {
     [...]
} ?>
```